# How to pre-process the background of this image in order to OCR the table properly?

Tags: pdf, adobe-photoshop, ocr, image-processing

I have to OCR the book of tables consisting of 500+ pages but the maker stamped every page. Can anybody help me on how should I process it in order to be able to recognize it let's say in FineReader? To erase it with some mask in Photoshop?
[image] [image: FineReader work]

Comment: Since the stippled watermark and the image itself are both monochrome, there is no simple way to differentiate them. Perhaps there's a high-end OCR application, with enough "intelligence" to separate wheat from chaff, and to recognize only digits, point and spaces, but I don't know of one.

Comment: The watermark was intentional by the author for conserving his copyright. You should rather get a clean document from the author himself.